# How to prohibit DTD entities

Tags: xml-parsing, xsd, libxml2

I'm using the XML Tree API and the XML Parser API in c++, and I would like to prohibit entities creation in my XML documents.
What is the best way to do that when using these API's?
I've only seen examples of how to prohibit DTD entities when using XML Reader, and none when using the XML Tree or Parser API.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "prohibit entities creation"?

Comment: I mean to treat syntax as this: "<!ENTITY entity-name "entity-value">" as illegal

Answer (score 0):

When using the tree API, you can call [xmlGetIntSubset](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-tree.html#xmlGetIntSubset) and inspect the `xmlDtd` structure to check whether a document contains entity declarations. When using the SAX parser, you can register an [entityDeclSAXFunc](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-parser.html#entityDeclSAXFunc) callback.